# How can I electronically sign an MS Word Document on the Mac?

Tags: microsoft-word, digital-signature

I'd like to electronically sign an MS Word document so I can send it over to someone without having to print it and manually sign it.

I have no idea where to begin with this, though.  How do you go about it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you want to embed an image of your signature? (Rather than applying [a digital signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature)?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have an image of your signature but have a tablet or a multitouch trackpad on the Mac (or, I suppose, the Magic Trackpad) you can look at [Autograph](http://tenonedesign.com/autograph.php)

I usually 'print' to PDF, and use [PDFPenPro](http://smilesoftware.com/PDFpenPro/index.html) to place my signature image, then flatten the file so the signature image can't be reused. I also then sign the document with GPG, but that might be more than you need.

P.S. I would be careful with embedding an image of your signature, because there's not a lot preventing the other party from using that signature in other documents etc. While I use a picture as well, I place it over a line (wherever the signature line would be in the document) AND flatten the PDF, so it can't be easily copied.

Comment: ended up going with Adobe Acrobat Pro.  Didn't realize that it could create digital signatures for me.